# как записать(byte,float.int) в переменную в коде

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Есть код Cli_DBRead(1000,48,4,UnsafeMutalabRawPointer!) С UnsafeMutalabRawPointer! надо считать переменную как это сделать. подскажите пожалуйста. Этот код считывает данные с контроллера и должен записать в UnsafeMutalabRawPointer! я не могу от туда считать и запись в переменную

Comment: обычно мы присваиваем вначале перемененную типа let a=int
 а как в коде записать переменную и присвоить ему значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По всей видимости это кортеж. Доступ к элементам кортежа осуществляется так

```
var (_, _, _, yourVar) =  Cli_DBRead
```

для теста

```
print(" necessaryVar - \(yourVar)")
```